# ubunutu commands to upload sql file to database

Tags: database, ubuntu, command

There is a database file in this path : /var/www/db.sql in our server.

size of .sql file is about 800mb.

we have to upload this sql file to the database name : "age"

**username : root,
password : pass ,
database password : dbpass**

i am trying this command . but its not working.

```
mysql -u root -ppass age db.sql
```

please give the correct command or is i am missing path of sql file?

please guide me about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
mysql -uroot -ppass age < /var/www/db.sql
```

or better is:

```
mysql -uroot -p age < /var/www/db.sql
```

Passing password as an MySQL argument is unsecure.

Comment: You must use full path for db.sql or go into db.sql directory and run !mysql command

Comment: this is path : /var/www/db.sql now please update the answer

Comment: Examples : cd /home/db_files/ && !mysql    Or mysql -uroot -p age < /home/db_files/db.sql

Comment: You must use Mysql's root password

Answer (score 1):

Which database you will be importing data to should be specified by `USING age;` at the top of the `.sql` file. After you make that change, execute:

`mysql -u root -ppass < db.sql`

So that the CRUD commands contained in the `.sql` file are sent to the mysql console.